# How to force ActiveRecord to ALWAYS insert, update, delete and retrieve from the database?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

We are using ActiveRecord stand-alone (not part of a Rails application) to do unit testing with RSpec. We are testing a trigger on the database that it inserts rows into an audit table.

The classes are:

Folder has many File

Folder has many FileAudit

The sequence of events is like this:

- Create Folder
- ***START TEST ONE***
- Create File
- Do some stuff to File
- Get Folder.file_audits
- Check associated FileAudit records
- Destroy File
- Destroy FileAudits
- ***END TEST ONE***
- ***START TEST TWO***
- Create File
- Do some other stuff to File
- Get Folder.file_audits
- Check associated FileAudit records
- Destroy File
- Destroy FileAudits
- ***END TEST TWO***
- Destroy Folder

The FileAudits from test one are getting destroyed, but not from test two. ActiveRecord seems to think that there is nothing new in that table to delete at the end of the second test.

I can do Folder.file_audits(true) to refresh the cache, but I would rather just disable any and all kinds of caching and have ActiveRecord just do what I tell it instead of it doing what it thinks is best.

I also need to set a flag on File to the same value and verify that the trigger did not create an audit record. When I set the flag to a different value, I can see the update statement in the log, but when I set it to the same value and save, there is no update in the log.

I am sure that the caching and etc. is fine for a web site, but we are not doing that. We need it to always get all records from the database and always update and delete no matter what. How can we do that?

We are using ActiveRecord 3.1.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess would be that there you are doing something with transactions in one of the tests.  If you are, you are effectively eliminating the outer transaction that wraps the unit test itself, in which case causes the unit test cleanup to have nothing to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to you or not, but I've had problems in the past with doing `model.save` instead of `model.save!`. Sometimes I would get validation errors on save, but without the bang the validation errors don't raise an actual exception, so I never know that the save wasn't successful.